# Is there an online video converter?

Tags: video, conversion

Does anyone know of any services that will convert a large video (1gb+)? 
I've a bunch of files I'm looking to convert from mkv to mp4's. I'm on an older Mac and I've looked at some sites like video toolbox but they limit to 600mb. I'm willing to pay.

Comment: How much are you willing to pay? Send the file to me, and I'll convert it for you :)

Comment: HAR HAR, Naw, I've learned to use mkvtools to pass-through the video, takes minutes.

Comment: @TheIrishGuy  Does this mean you have found a solution?  If so, please share it with the rest of us by posting an answer to your question.

Comment: Don't you spend more time uploading / downloading the video than converting it directly on your old computer ? Unless you have a really fast internet connection and a really old computer !

Answer (score 2):

How old of a Mac? [MPEG Streamclip](http://squared5.com) is a great option.

> This free software requires at least Mac OS X 10.2 (Jaguar) and QuickTime 6. It is also compatible with Mac OS X 10.3.x (Panther), Mac OS X 10.4.x (Tiger), Mac OS X 10.5.x (Leopard), Mac OS X 10.6.x (Snow Leopard), OS X Lion, and QuickTime 7. It works with PowerPC and Intel based Macs.

Unless you are living the the Stone Age and have a Mac running 10.1 or lower, you'll be fine.

You can batch convert files by going to List>Batch List:

[image: List>Batch list]

You'll be presented with a screen like this:

[image: Batch List window]

You can add files from there and convert them.

Comment: Your link is already not actual.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Zencoder](http://zencoder.com/) ist one of the biggest online video converter. But it's [not free](http://zencoder.com/pricing/) and it's not made for home use. But if you want to build your own video portal (like Youtube), you are in their target group. For example the [Drupal video modul](http://drupal.org/project/video) supports Zencoder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one: Youtube!
As Youtube now supports all common video codecs (just tested it for H.264, H.265 and VP9) and practically all audio codecs and then converts the uploaded video to VP9 based video (MKV or webm) and H.264 based video (MP4), you can just upload your MKV and then use a tool like 4k Video Downloader, JDownloader 2 or aTube Catcher to download the created MP4.
BUT Youtube deletes all protected content (even if you upload it to private), so this might not help you at all.